Error: "Paint.setShadowLayer is not supported"
I just created a home page (menu) with 2 image buttons, but I am getting this error:
The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:

Paint.setShadowLayer is not supported.

What does it mean? And how can I solve it?
